# How to set an object function equal to another

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

Assuming I have the following object:

```
let obj={
    childone: (value) => {
        return value+1;
    },
    childtwo: (value) => {
        return value+3;
    },
    childsingle: (value) => {
        return value+1;
    }
};
```

Is there any method to set `obj.childsingle` equal to `obj.childone` within the same declaration?

I'm trying to achieve `childsingle=childone` within the object declaration.

**I also tried to use `get` as per duplicated suggested answers.**

However, after using this:

```
let obj = {
    childone: (value) => {
        return value+1;
    },
    childtwo: (value) => {
        return value+3;
    },
    get childsingle() {
        return this.childone;
    }
};
```

I get `handleError TypeError: childsingle is not a function`.

Comment: You can define the function as a const before the object declaration and pass the same function to both of them

Comment: Within object literal - NO.

Comment: Isn't this related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616202/self-references-in-object-literals-initializers

Comment: yes @WiktorZychla but I cannot use *this* because is related to the class.

Comment: Works: `let obj={
        childone: (value) => {
            return value+1;
        },
        childtwo: (value) => {
            return value+3;
        },
        childsingle: (value) => {
            return obj.childone(value)
        }
    };`

Comment: @mplungjan doesn't make any sense.... I mean I would like to not rewrite a function.

Comment: Then the answer is no

Comment: Don't use arrow function `childsingle: function(value)  {return this.childone(value)}`

Answer (score 4):

You can use `getter` method for `childsingle` declaration. Example is shown below.

Here in it will always return `childone` when you call for `childsingle` even if you update `childone` `childone` will always point to latest `childone`.

For more information refer [Defining getters and setters Section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Defining_getters_and_setters)

```js
let obj = {
    childone: (value) => {
        return value+1;
    },
    childtwo: (value) => {
        return value+3;
    },
    get childsingle() {
        return this.childone;
    }
};

console.log(obj.childsingle(10));
```

Comment: Nice, but I got an error in console... *handleError TypeError: childsingle is not a function*.

Comment: @Vixed Are you using `Internet Explorer`? Check browser compatibility here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get#Browser_compatibility

Comment: No Karam... Chrome...

Answer (score 3):

What is the reason to avoid:

```
let obj = {
    childone: (value) => {
        return value + 1;
    },
    childtwo: (value) => {
        return value + 3;
    },
    childsingle: (value) => {
        return obj.childone(value);
    }
};
```

It provides:

```
console.log(obj.childone(1)); // 2
console.log(obj.childsingle(2)); // 3
```

Lexical scoping keeps in honest in more advanced scenarios too:

```
function getObj() {
    const obj = {
        childone: (value) => {
            return value + 1;
        },
        childtwo: (value) => {
            return value + 3;
        },
        childsingle: (value) => {
            return obj.childone(value);
        }
    };

    return obj;
}

const example = getObj();

console.log(example.childone(1));
console.log(example.childsingle(2));
```

Comment: @Fentom +1 for the explanation, but I'm trying to set only an object fn equal to another, not to set a new object everytime I need it.

Comment: @Vixed the top example does that - the function was just to show lexical scoping is preserved if you pass the object around.

Answer (score 2):

You might think of something like this:

```
let obj={
    childone: (value) => {
        return value+1;
    },
    childtwo: (value) => {
        return value+3;
    },
    childsingle: obj.childone
    }
};
```

But that doesn't work. You have to do it in two steps.

The way the assign operator (`=`) works, is as follows. It uses the right side of the operator, computes its value and assigns that value (which is a reference to an object in your case) to the variable on the left side.

So at the time the right hand side of the assign operator is assembled, the `obj` variable is not existent. So you will get an error.

This will also not work

```
let obj={
    childone: (value) => {
        return value+1;
    },
    childtwo: (value) => {
        return value+3;
    },
    childsingle: this.childone
    }
};
```

because `this` will not refer to the current object.

This will not work, because `childone` is not defined

```
let obj={
    childone: (value) => {
        return value+1;
    },
    childtwo: (value) => {
        return value+3;
    },
    childsingle: childone
    }
};
```

This is the way to go:

```
let obj={
    childone: (value) => {
        return value+1;
    },
    childtwo: (value) => {
        return value+3;
    },
};
obj.childsingle = obj.childone;
```

But beware, if you are planning to change the `childone` function and think that the `childsingle` function will change as well, that is not true.

Before changing `childone`, we have two keys of the object (childone and childsingle) that are references to the same function. But childone and childsingle are not related elsewise. If you change chilone this will be a reference to a new function and childsingle will remain the same old function

Comment: `let obj={ childone: (value) => { return value+1; }, childtwo: (value) => { return value+3; }, childsingle: (value) => { return obj.childone(value) } };` also works

Comment: @mplungjan I saw this as comment on the OP. This does not apply as the OP states

Comment: I do not see why that is not as valid as obj.childsingle = obj.childone - with the additional opportunity to detect which one was called without duplicating the processing

Comment: It **is** valid. It still does not apply to the OP